# How to bind to a property of a list in a Listview

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I'm trying to pull the image i'm going to show the structure could anyone explain how I could bind to it?

What I have tried is saying `Binding: images[5];`

Any Idea's?

I wanted to simply just bind to featured_src but its not part of the wrapper, It doesn't return along with the json In the C# application but on the postman response I do get the Featured_src (Featured Image)

Method

```
            RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://azipit.co.za/mica-market-app/wp-json/wc/v3/", "ck_0112f135e2f9b32cc147f28028fd621f919bc890", "cs_38ea21f4d63eb96a801868993b66065dcb0362fa");
            WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);

            var p = await wc.Product.GetAll(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                    {"tag", Suppliers.tagid },
                    { "per_page", "80" } }); ;


            productsListView.ItemsSource = p;
```

Response

Screens to make it easier:

[image: Response 1]

[image]

The class:

```
 [DataContract]
    public class Product : JsonObject
    {
        public Product();

        public static string Endpoint { get; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public bool? shipping_required { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public ProductDimension dimensions { get; set; }
        public decimal? weight { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public bool? sold_individually { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public bool? backordered { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public bool? backorders_allowed { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string backorders { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string stock_status { get; set; }
        public int? stock_quantity { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public bool? manage_stock { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string tax_class { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string tax_status { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string button_text { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string external_url { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public bool? shipping_taxable { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string shipping_class { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string shipping_class_id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public bool? reviews_allowed { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public List<int> grouped_products { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public List<int> variations { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public List<ProductDefaultAttribute> default_attributes { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public List<ProductAttributeLine> attributes { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public List<ProductImage> images { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public List<ProductTagLine> tags { get; set; }
```

Product Image Class:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class ProductImage
    {
        public ProductImage();

        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public long? id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public DateTime? date_created { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public DateTime? date_created_gmt { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public DateTime? date_modified { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public DateTime? date_modified_gmt { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string src { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string alt { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 <ListView x:Name="productsListView"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"                       
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      SeparatorVisibility="None">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <Frame HasShadow="True" Margin="8">
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Label x:Name="something" Text="{Binding title}" FontSize="Large"/>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding images[5]}"/> 
                                        <Label Text="{Binding date_created, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Italic"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding price }"/>
                                        <Label Text="{x:Binding enable_html_description  }" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                        <Label Text="{x:Binding sku}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding type}" BindingContext="{Binding type}"/>
                                        <Button BindingContext="{Binding id}" Clicked="ProductClicked"></Button>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>

                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer my own question.

Correct me if there are other ways or better ways but

Generally How I found the binding is by going down the local response.

so in my case

p --> [0] --> images --> [0] --> src --> Magnifying glass to view --> Expression is your binding in my case again --> p[0].images[0].src

So my Binding for image:

```
 <Image Source="{Binding images[0].src}"/>
```

So I obviously just want the first image of every Product but this can be extended to any property I believe, So If I wanted to 3rd image of every product in the list

It would be

```
 <Image Source="{Binding images[2].src}"/>
```

Or if I wanted the id of every 1st image it would be

```
 <Image Source="{Binding images[0].id}"/>
```